# Distribution of lengths of contiguous regions when colouring $m$ out of $N$ sites

Tags: combinatorics, statistics

Consider a circular chain of $N$ white sites. You randomly colour $M$ sites black. How many boundaries between contiguous white and black regions are there?

[There has been a similar question (2d)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2610128/expected-number-of-same-colour-regions-in-a-tiled-floor), but I'm not convinced the answers are correct. The first one clearly fails for small $a,b$ and I'm not sure whether or how the second approach would generalise to what I'm asking.

The end result is a probability distribution of integers between $1$ and $N$ (the number of boundaries is trivially 0 for $M=0$ and $M=N$). And I am most interested in the limit $N\to\infty,$ $M/N=\text{constant}$.

So instead of the above, a simple question might be to just consider an infinite chain and a probability $p$ of colouring any site black. One could think about writing down the probability for a region of length $n$, which is $p^n(1-p)^2$. Somehow this doesn't lead to the full answer yet (contrary to what is claimed in the link, I think), because we need to also consider how much space a configuration takes up. This also doesn't take into account the white space in between.

So I am tempted to consider the following:

- Define regions $R_n$ of $n$ black sites followed by one white site.
- If there is a region $R_n$, it takes up $n+1$ sites and contains two boundaries. So the associated "boundary density" is $2/(n+1)$.
- total number of boundaries would be $2\rho(n)/(n+1)$, where $\rho(n)$ is the density of region $R_n$, which I don't know.

Another approach that seems promising, but that I couldn't get to work either is to consider the probability $p_n$ for a randomly chosen black site in the configuration to be part of a region of length $n$. This would allow you to find the boundary density as $\sum_n 2p_n/(n+1)$, I think.

Are there better ways to think about this?

EDIT:
Could it be as simple as calculating the probability that to the right of a randomly picked site there is a boundary? The probability for this to be the case is
$$ p_\mathrm{bdry}= 2p(1-p). $$
Is this the correct density of boundaries?

Comment: If you want to compute the expected value of the number of boundaries, then the idea in your last comment in sufficient. The probability a particular pair of adjacent sites have a boundary between them is $\frac{M}{N}\frac{N-M}{N-1}+\frac{N-M}{N}\frac{M}{N-1}=\frac{2M(N-M)}{N(N-1)}$, and the expected number of boundaries is this quantity times the number of pairs of adjacent sites, so $\frac{2M(N-M)}{N-1}$.

Comment: Thank you, Mike!